# PHP, regular expression and preg_replace, need some help

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need help with little replacing:

```
Some text [ id ]
```

to...

```
Some text | id
```

I'm new in regular expression and I just don't know, how to safely keep text inside [ ]... And I don't want to use str_replace and trim... I have to use expressions (don't ask why :D )... Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you need to account for nested brackets?

Comment: No... Just like it is...

Comment: Which parts are variable? Something like `\s\[\s*(\S+)\s*\]` will capture a single token inside square brackets preceded by whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for non-nested square brackets:

```
preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]/", "|$1", "Some text [ id ]")
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Some text | id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for such a simple task,  [str_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do it.

```
$str = str_replace(array("[","]"), array("|", ""), $str);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Some text | id
```

Using regex to do something like this is like asking Einstein to solve 2 + 2.